# C++: Duda con herencia

Tags: c++

estoy aprendiendo como funciona la herencia y el polimorfismo,mi problema es que no entiendo porque pasa lo siguiente:

Gato es un objeto de tipo `DomesticCat` que hereda de la clase `Feline` al heredar de esta clase hereda los metodos que esta tiene y los que heredó de `Mammal`,mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Porque el objeto de tipo Gato puede hacer uso de los metodos `set_circus_name` y `get_circus_name`?
entiendo que la clase Gato hereda estos metodos pero al crear un objeto de tipo gato se usa el segundo constructor de la clase  `Feline` el cual no inicializa el atributo `Circus_name` que es necesario para que estas 2 funciones funcionen, sin embargo si se llaman estas 2 funciones usando un objeto de tipo `Gato` funcionan sin ningun problema

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DomesticCat.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DomesticCat* Gato = new DomesticCat(2015,"Montevideo","Gato Persa","Franco");

    Gato->set_circus_name("Circo");
    std::cout<<Gato->get_circus_name();


    return 0;
}
```

Feline.h

```
#include "Mammal.h"

class Feline : public Mammal{
    private:
        std::string Circus_name;
    public:
        Feline(int birth_year,std::string birth_place,std::string breed,std::string Circus_name) : Mammal(birth_year,birth_place,breed){
            this->Circus_name = Circus_name;
        }

        Feline(int birth_year,std::string birth_place,std::string breed) : Mammal(birth_year,birth_place,breed){};


        std::string print_diet(){
            return "La dieta del felino es a base de carne\n";          
        }       

        void set_circus_name(std::string new_circus_name){
            this->Circus_name = new_circus_name;
        }

        std::string get_circus_name(){
            return Circus_name;

        }       
        ~Feline(){

        }
};

#endif
```

DomesticCat.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Feline.h"

class DomesticCat : public Feline{
    private:
        std::string Owners_name;
    public:
        DomesticCat(int birth_year,std::string birth_place,std::string breed,std::string Owners_name) : Feline(birth_year,birth_place,breed){
            this->Owners_name = Owners_name;
        }

        std::string print_diet(){
            return "La dieta del gato es con Whiskas\n";
        }

        void set_owners_name(std::string Owners_name){
            this->Owners_name = Owners_name;
        }

        std::string get_owners_name(){
            return Owners_name;
        }

        ~DomesticCat(){         
        }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C++, **es imposible** no inicializar una variable-miembro de una clase.

Un simple código de demostración:

```
struct CustomType {
  CustomType( ) { std::cout << "Constructor !!\n"; }
};

struct Test {
  CustomType ct;
  Test( ) { }
};

Test t;
```

Observa que, en el constructor de la clase `Test`, **no inicializamos** el miembro `ct`. Y, sin embargo, la salida es:

> Constructor !!

En caso de que, como en el ejemplo, **no se inicialize** en el constructor, C++ **automágicamente** llamará al constructor sin argumentos del tipo indicado.

Es mas, si modificamos nuestro código de ejemplo:

```
struct CustomType {
  CustomType( ) = delete;
  CustomType( int ) { std::cout << "Constructor !!\n"; }
};

struct Test {
  CustomType ct;
  Test( ) { }
};

Test t;
```

Ahora, `CustomType` **no tiene** constructor sin argumentos. Intentamos compilarlo ...

> error: use of deleted function `CustomType::CustomType()`

Y confirmamos lo dicho inicialmente: **es imposible** dejarnos un miembro sin inicializar.

Ahora, vamos a usar la herencia en lugar de composición. Un sencillo cambio a nuestro código:

```
struct Base {
  Base( ) = delete;
  Base( int ) { std::cout << "Constructor !!\n"; }
};

struct Test : public Base { 
  Test( ) { }
};

Test t;
```

Intentamos compilar ...

> error: use of deleted function ‘Base::Base()’

Pues ya lo vemos:

- Toda clase inicializa **siempre** todas sus variables-miembro. Bien de forma explícita, bien de forma implícita (al constructor sin argumentos).
- Toda clase hija llama **siempre** a un constructor de su clase padre. Bien de forma explícita, bien de forma implícita (al constructor sin argumentos).

#### Nota sobre los tipos nativos

Una *peculiaridad* de este mecanismo de inicialización son **los tipos nativos**: `int`, `float`, `char *`, `int[]`, ...

Conceptualmente, dichos tipos **también** tienen un *constructor sin argumentos* ... que se limita ¡ a no hacer nada ! :-O

Dicho de otra manera, todos los tipos nativos **tienen que ser inicializados de forma explícita**: su constructor sin argumentos deja la memoria tal cual, con la *basura* que hubiera en memoria con anterioridad:

```
struct Test {
  int value;
};

Test t;

std::cout << t.value << '\n';
```

> 234943860384

Comment: Te falta indicar que los tipos nativos no se inicializan solos, aunque sean variables miembro

Comment: Bueno, si se inicializan ¿ no ? pero con valor indeterminado ... son curiosos los tipos nativos :-) edito

Comment: no se inicializan... la basura que tienen es la que ya estaba en esa región de memoria

Comment: Si, a eso me refiero. Conceptualmente, podríamos decir que su constructor por defecto no hace nada, y la memoria queda con la *basura* que estuviera allí antes.

Comment: pero si no hace nada y es como si no existiese... entonces no se inicializan

Comment: Es por no *romper* la conceptualidad. Veo mejor decir `un constructor que no hace nada` que decir `no tienen constructor`. Lo primero no rompe la generalidad de la idea que quiero expresar en la respuesta.

Comment: si te fijas, al crear plantillas puedes inicializar un tipo genérico como `t: T()` y entonces, los tipos nativos... **sí se inicializan**

Comment: Cierto. La verdad es que no había pensado en eso :-) Pero no voy a extender mas la respuesta. ¡ Muy bunea observación !

Comment: Entonces al usar las funciones ```set_circus_name()``` y  ```get_circus_name()``` con objetos de clase DomesticCat, C++ se da cuenta que no esta inicializada la variable ```Circus_name``` y la inicializa?

Comment: @Franco Inicializa **todas** las variables en el constructor. Y, si hay herencia de clases, inicializa **todas** las variables de **todas** las clases implicadas en la cadena de herencia. Cada constructor de una clase llama, aunque tu no lo veas, al constructor de su clase padre.

Comment: Ok,se inicializan todas las variables aun asi no se llame a su constructor (C++ lo hara automaticamente), pero ¿Porque no tira ningun error cuando el objeto tipo DomesticCat usa esa variable si es privada de la clase Feline?